# Can the TableView have multiple headers?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've attached an image. Can a tableview have multiple headers and be grouped by a sub model?

My model structure looks something like this.

```csharp
public class ModuleViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<MediaViewModel> Media { get; set; }
}

public class MediaViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public ModuleSectionViewModel ModuleSection {get; set;}
}

public class ModuleSectionViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

1. The view you're seeing in the image is the ModuleView
2. The TableView (the sliding navigation bit) would bind it's source to the Media property
3. The table would be grouped by the ModuleSection.Title property

is this possible? if so, where would I start?

*to add complication, I prefer doing my bindings in the Xaml :)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`TableView` is not fully bindable right now. But you can achieve similar result by subclassing it, and assigning the `TableView.Root` property to a constructed `TableRoot` in a `OnBindingContextChanged()` override.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps with multiple categories/groups? I'm not doubting you, just not sure how to accomplish it.